# Option for entity field

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am bulding a symfony form, in this form, I want the user to select multiple ball (A, B, C), so I use an entity field.
Here is my formbuilder:

```
$builder->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'name'))
    ->add('ball', 'entity', array('class' => 'MyBallkBundle:Ball', 'property' => 'name','label' => 'Balls', 'multiple' => true))
    ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'save'));
```

But I would like the user to be able to set the quantity for each ball, is there a way to do that in symfony 2 ?

Comment: how could you store quantity?

Answer (score 0):

If you want select and input to add quantity, you can create a custom form type to do so. Then you ll call a collection of it in the primary form.

Comment: You need to tell more information on what you want to do, coz right now it's pretty vague. But I can already tell you that if you want to display all your entities and a input for each with the quantity, you'll have a hard time to do so. (Such questions have already been posted there)